# calculating $\lim\limits _{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{e^{x}}{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{2}}\right)$ using taylor polynomials

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital, indeterminate-forms

I am trying to calculate the limit $$\lim\limits _{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{e^{x}}{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{2}}\right)$$ using taylor polynomials. I tried using L'Hôpital's rule, but it was tedious. the final answer should be $\frac{1}{12}$.

I tried taylor many times but couldn't make it work. here is my best attempt:

$$\lim\limits _{x\to0}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{e^{x}}{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{2}}\right)=\lim\limits _{x\to0}\left(\frac{\left(e^{x}-1\right)^{2}-x^{2}e^{x}}{x^{2}}\right)=\lim\limits _{x\to0}\left(\frac{\left(1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{6}+R_{3}\left(x\right)-1\right)^{2}-x^{2}\left(1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{6}+R_{3}\left(x\right)\right)}{x^{2}}\right)=\lim\limits _{x\to0}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{3}R_{3}\left(x\right)x^{4}+R_{3}^{2}\left(x\right)x^{2}+2x^{2}R_{3}\left(x\right)+\frac{x^{6}}{36}+\frac{x^{4}}{12}}{x^{2}}\right)=\lim\limits _{x\to0}\left(\frac{R_{3}\left(x\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}x^{4}+R_{3}\left(x\right)x^{2}+2x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}}\right)=\lim\limits _{x\to0}\left(R_{3}\left(x\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}x^{2}+R_{3}\left(x\right)+2\right)\right)$$

the number $\frac{1}{12}$ appears here but then goes away since $x^4$ goes to zero. There must be a simpler way then opening the brackets here, and making all those tedious calculations.

Comment: where went the $(e^x-1)^2$ at the denominator in your first equality ?

Comment: @Surb made a mistake. should've been there. but even then, I still need to calculate all of the squared expressions, there must be a simpler way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $(e^x-1)^2-x^2e^x=e^{2x}-(x^2+2)e^x+1$ and the first $5$ terms of the Taylor series of this function are simply $\frac{x^4}{12}$. And the first $5$ terms of the Taylor series of $x^2(e^x-1)^2$ are simply $x^4$. Therefore your limit is indeed $\frac1{12}$.

Comment: how do you calculate  the taylor series of this? by substituting 2x=t in the expression $e^{t}=1+t+\frac{t^{2}}{2}+\ldots$?

Comment: and how can you quickly calculate the taylor series of $x^2(e^x-1)^2$? by multiplying the series of e^x-1, which is $x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\ldots$, with $x^2$, which gives $t^{3}+\frac{t^{4}}{2}+\ldots$?

Comment: You have\begin{align}e^{2x}&=1+2x+\frac{(2x)^2}2+\frac{(2x)^3}6+\frac{(2x)^4}{24}+\cdots\\&=1+2x+2x^2+\frac43x^3+\frac23x^4+\cdots\end{align}and\begin{align}(x^2+2)e^x&=(2+x^2)\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\cdots\right)\\&=2+2x+2x^2+\frac43x^3+\frac7{12}x^4+\cdots\end{align}

Comment: might be silly.. but I managed to get here using your method, how do I finish and show the  limit is $\frac{1}{12}$? $$\lim\limits _{x\to0}\left(\frac{1+2x+2x^{2}+\frac{4}{3}x^{3}+\frac{2}{3}x^{4}+o\left(x^{4}\right)-\left(2+2x+2x^{2}+\frac{4}{3}x^{3}+\frac{7}{12}x^{4}+o\left(x^{4}\right)\right)}{x^{4}+o\left(x^{4}\right)}\right)=\lim\limits _{x\to0}\left(\frac{-1+\frac{1}{12}x^{4}+o\left(x^{4}\right)-o\left(x^{4}\right)}{x^{4}+o\left(x^{4}\right)}\right)$$

Comment: That is wrong. As I wrote in my answer, the first five terms of the Taylor series of the numerator are simply $\frac{x^4}{12}$, not $-1+\frac{x^4}{12}$. If it was as you wrote, the limit would be $-\infty$, not $\frac1{12}$.